# How to use lambda functions in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have an object that needs a function passed to it in order to work.  Something like

```
int doSomething(string a, int b, string(*lookUpFunction)(string a, int b)) {
    return lookUpFunction(a,b).length():
}
```

This is simplified to just include needed parameters and correct return types.  I believe I have defined this correctly but please correct me if I am wrong.  lookUpFunction takes a string and an int and returns a string.

Where my problem comes in is using this function.  I would think I would use like this

```
class x {
    DataBase* db;
public:
    int myFunc();
}


int x::myFunc() {
    return doSomething("a",1,[this](string a, int b)->string {
        return db->someFuncThatTakesStringAndInt(a,b);
    });
}
```

But my IDE throws errors.  If I remove "this" it says db isn't accessible.  With it in it says the lambda function is not castable to correct format.

Comment: You want the parameter to be a `std::function` rather than a function pointer.

Comment: One of the skills you need as a programmer is to read documentation. Have a look at [introduction to lambda functions learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-lambdas-anonymous-functions/) then you will need to learn about function templates. And you can write something like `template <typname function_type> auto dosomething(function_type fn){fn();};` and call it with a lambda like this : `dosomething([]{ std::cout << "this is a lambda\n"; });`.  Or in your case `dosomething(std::function<void (std::string,int) fn>` is also an option.

Comment: See [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: A lambda is convertible to a function pointer *only* if it doesn't capture anything.

Comment: @BoP I was just going to say this too. So no do not try to convert lambdas to function pointers. Use a template or std::function. They are much more flexible.

Comment: Thanks I will have to try both the template and std function approach and see which works better.  Thanks again.

Comment: IMO question suffers form [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). You should describe what code should do not how you try achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `doSomething()` function is taking in a plain C-style function pointer for its `lookUpFunction` callback.

However, a *capturing* lambda is not convertible to a function pointer, only a *non-capturing* lambda is convertible. You are capturing `this`, which is why you can't pass in your lambda as shown.

Instead of a function pointer, your `doSomething()` function will need to take in a callback object as either a `std::function` or a template parameter, eg:

```
int doSomething(string a, int b, std::function<string(string, int)> lookUpFunction) {
    return lookUpFunction(a,b).length():
}
```

```
template<typename Callable>
int doSomething(string a, int b, Callable lookUpFunction) {
    return lookUpFunction(a,b).length():
}
```

Now, you can pass your *capturing* lambda to either one.